# lightning:input methods - which are available?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, documentation, lightning-inputfield

Mistake in Lightning Component docs or my misunderstanding?

From [the Lightning Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) at the very bottom of the "Documentation" tab it reads,

> This component supports the following methods.
>
> focus
>
> setCustomValidity
>
> reportValidity
>
> checkValidity

while the "Methods" section of the "Specification" tab lists,

> showHelpMessageIfInvalid
>
> focus

If I inspect the obj with `typeof x.y === "function" they all seem available.

Why the difference in these lists?

Comment: Why ask this question? It seems to me you had a question, you were able to answer the question on your own. Rather then ask a "why the difference" question, ask the question you wanted an answer to and then post an answer to your own question. This allows you to get any information you find useful out to the public. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

Just to reiterate the obvious, It seems the issue is with the docs. I saw this in several other components as well.

For example [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/specification) component doc is consistent but [lightning:textarea](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:textarea/documentation) has same issue. There could be some more components with inconsistencies.

Other than confirming the issue, i don't think anybody here can do much about it. Things are improving with every release, We can only hope that docs will improve as well with time.

Comment: In the Lightning Platform Roadmap Sessions at DF18 this past week, that was one of the things I recall being promised was improvements in the documentation. I do not recall the delivery date for those improvements.